# nothing happens when using bootstrap-switch

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-switch

I'm unable to run the bootstrap switch in my application.

In my gemfile, I have

```
gem 'bootstrap-switch-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
```

In my application.html.haml I have (I put a breakpoint: it is executed after loading)

```
  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $('input:checkbox').bootstrapSwitch();
    });
```

In my application.css I have

```
*= require_directory .
*= require_self
*= require_directory ./../fonts
*= require bootstrap3-switch
```

In my application.js I have

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and finally, in my view code, I have the following 3 attempts:

```
= form_for(group) do |g|
  = g.label :is_private, "is_private"
  = g.check_box :is_private, :data => { :size=>'small', 'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=>'YES', 'off-text'=>'NO' } 

%input{ :type => "checkbox",  :name => "mycheckbox" }

.switch{ "data-on" => "primary", "data-off" => "info"}
  %input{ :type => "checkbox" }
```

The result is always a standard check box.

Anyone can suggest where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way.

I needed to insert the following lines

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').bootstrapSwitch();
  });
```

into any of the .html.haml files where I want to use the switches.

This appear strange to me because I already inserted the same code in my application.html.haml end it should be enough.

If there is a better suggestion please, post it.